# In that scenario, how will the editor handle my academic paper (a revision)?

Tags: publications, elsevier

I submitted a paper to the Elsevier journal and got positive feedback from the editor and two referees with only 8 comments. However, after I submitted the revision, one of the referees declined (or ignored) and another accepted the invitation to the second round but didn't upload any review report. So, how will the editor handle this paper???

Answer (score 5):

What happens if, after revision ...

- A reviewer declines to review the revision (or does not respond). The editor has several options. They can 1) check the revision themselves, might not be possible if they lack the subject expertise; 2) invite another reviewer; 3) make a decision anyway.
- Accepts the review invitation but then goes incommunicado. Same as previous, with an extra option 4: wait.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers. The editorial board has withdrawn the review invitation and hasn't sent extra invitations. Perhaps, they might check the revision themselves.